# plsql code to get multiple no of students name

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to get multiple students name and want to display it.

expect input :

```
total no of students: 2
```

enter the names :

```
jack
thomas
```

output :

```
jack 
thomas
```

Tried query :

```
DECLARE
    NAME VARCHAR2(30);
    total number(10);
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('total no of students');
    TOTAL := '&total_peop';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('enter the names');
    FOR I IN 1..TOTAL LOOP
        NAME[i] := '&enter_the_name';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(name[i]);
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: *"Tried query"* - Good! And what happened? Please check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what kind of information we need to be able to help you.

Comment: SQL or PL/SQL is not necessarily meant for interactive programming like this one. You could first fetch  data from the database and then  use other languages like shell scripting,java or python to perform operations with user inputs. Also, what is `NAME[i]` ?There is no such array operator in Oracle.

Comment: i just want to input 2 names and display it that all i want !! when i tried this its not asking for multiple names

Comment: You only have two substitution variables: `&total_peop` and `&enter_the_name` - so these are the only variables the script will prompt the user for. After getting these values, it will *then* and only then run your PL/SQL block. Doesn't matter how many times the loop runs, the interaction with the user has already finished before it starts. As said before, PL/SQL is not an interactive programming language.

Comment: I think you need a completly different approach. Although his is not realy what PLSQL is build for. But to answer your question. I would suggest making a `procedure` that has 2 input parameters one for 'number of students' and one for the 'names'. Make the procedure to split the names into seperate names, and let those print on the screen.